# ASP.NET Webforms, ModalPopupExtender, Bootstrap: Where is this inline CSS coming from?

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I am trying to use a ModalPopupExtender to implement a cancel dialog on a ASP.NET WebForms page. I am using Bootstrap so I don't have to think too much about the CSS as I am not a designer. I am finding though that I cannot get the ModalPopupExtender to position correctly. Even though the CssClass is set to Bootstraps Modal class it seems that there is inline style being inserted somewhere that overrides it. Where is this coming from? Sorry I don't have a Webforms background...thanks!

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender PopupControlID="ConfirmCancelPanel" runat="server"
    CancelControlID="ConfirmCancelCancelButton" TargetControlID="CancelButton" />
<%-- The modal popup panel used for confirming cancel--%>
<asp:Panel ID="ConfirmCancelPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modal" Style="display: none">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5>Cancel purchase and return to .........</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <asp:Button ID="ConfirmCancelOkButton" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddConsumable" Text="Ok"
            OnClick="ConfirmCancelOkButton_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
        <asp:Button ID="ConfirmCancelCancelButton" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Generated output:

[image: InlineCSS]
[image: InlineCSS2]

Answer (score 0):

This "thing" is generated bo AJAX Toolkit JavaScripts.